# IONIC 4, lector de huellas Fingerprint y Firestore

Tags: firebase, ionic, google-cloud-firestore

Espero la pregunta sea valida para la pagina si no lo es lo elimino sin ningún problema. Gracias de antemano. Tengo una consulta sobre el funcionamiento del lector de huellas en android con ionic 4 y el modo en el que trabaja.

No es respecto al código, sino la manera de funcionar. Cada vez que quiero mostrar el valor result.withFingerprint que me devuelve el lector de huellas el valor cambia. y de hecho esa es la duda!. Creo que asumí el hecho de que al tomar mi huella el resultado iba ser siempre el mismo(y es porque al parecer todavía no entiendo como funciona). Si alguien puede asesorarme como sacar un único valor solo para mi huella se lo agradecería ya que necesito compararlo con un dato almacenado en Firestore.

Les dejo el código de la función que saca ese dato:

```
show2(){
    if(FingerprintAIO.isAvailable()){
      FingerprintAIO.show({
        clientId: 'Fingerprint-Demo',
        clientSecret: 'password',
        disableBackup: true,
      })  
      .then((result: any)=> {

// almaceno el valor en la variable resultado
// y la visualizo con {{resultado.withFingerprint}}

        this.resultado =  result;
        console.log(result)}
      )
      .catch((err: any )=> {
        this.error = err;
        console.log(err)}
      );

    }
  }
```

Gracias otra vez.

Answer (score 0):

El resultado varía por la posición en que tu dedo es colocado en el lector de huellas, este reconoce patrones y los transforma a un formato conveniente que comparará tu huella que acabas de ingresar con los valores válidos ingresados cuando guardas tu huella. Se comparan mediante rangos que deben coincidir para que sea válido. De esta manera funciona un lector de huellas, aunque puede cambiar según la funcionalidad o plugin que se esté utilizando, espero haberte ayudado.